# ListView's ImageView onClick changing other rows also

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView`. There is an `ImageView` in the row of the ListView. I have attached onClick attribute to the ImageView and my onClick function is

```
public void alarmClick(View v)
{
    ImageView bell = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.mEventImage);
    bell.setImageResource(R.drawable.bell_on);
    if(bell.getTag() == null)
    {
        bell.setImageResource(R.drawable.bell_on);
        bell.setTag(R.drawable.bell_on);
    }
    else if((Integer)bell.getTag() == R.drawable.bell_on)
    {
        bell.setImageResource(R.drawable.bell_off);
        bell.setTag(R.drawable.bell_off);
    }
    else
    {
        bell.setImageResource(R.drawable.bell_on);
        bell.setTag(R.drawable.bell_on);
    }
}
```

I am trying to toggle the `ImageView` source but when i click the `ImageView` many other rows `ImageView` which are not on the screen at that time are also toggled. This is may be because the views are recycled in the `ListView`. Any suggestions how to do for each unique row.

Adapter Class

```
package com.example.drawer;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class EventAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EventList> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<EventList> data;
    int layoutResourceId;

    public EventAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<EventList> data) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        this.layoutResourceId = textViewResourceId;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        EventHolder holder =  null;
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflator = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflator.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new EventHolder();
            holder.coord = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.eventCoor);
            holder.icon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.eventName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.eventNam);
            holder.location = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.eventLoc);
            holder.time = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.eventTime);
            row.setTag(holder);

        }
        else
        {
            holder = (EventHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        EventList listItem = data.get(position);
        ImageHelper imageHelper = new ImageHelper();
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ipl);
        Bitmap newIcon = imageHelper.getRoundedCornerBitmap(icon, 200);
        holder.coord.setText(listItem.coord);
        holder.eventName.setText(listItem.eventName);
        holder.location.setText(listItem.location);
        holder.time.setText(listItem.time);
        holder.icon.setImageBitmap(newIcon);
        holder.id = listItem.id;
        holder.day = listItem.day;
        //Log.d("ListView", "Executed");
        return row;

    }


    static class EventHolder
    {
        ImageView icon;
        TextView eventName;
        TextView location;
        TextView time;
        TextView coord;
        int id;
        int day;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should include your `ListView` class and your `Adapter` class.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?? Could you please post the solution, as I am having the same problem too... Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the reason is that the view is recycled and the same ImageView is coming for a different row.

Your list item - EventList, should now if the bell for it should be on or off, and in getView to set it appropriately. This would mean if the user taped of first item and set the bell on, when other item is reusing that view it will change it back to off.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Cursor Loaders and let your Activity/Fragment implement LoaderCallbacks, using a cursor is fairly straight forward. Manage your EventData using an Sqlite database or any other and use a ContentProvider to retrieve your data

Also let your EventAdapter extend CursorAdapter and then override the following methods:-

```
public class EventAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    int layoutResourceId;

    public EventAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) 
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = textViewResourceId;
    }

    static class EventHolder
    {
       final ImageView icon;
       final ImageView bell;
       final TextView eventName;
       final TextView location;
       final TextView time;
       final TextView coord;
       final int id;
       final int day;

       EventHolder(View view)
        {
           coord = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.eventCoor);
           icon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
           bell = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.mEventImage);
           eventName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.eventNam);
           location = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.eventLoc);
           time = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.eventTime);
           id = -1;
           day = -1;
        }
    }
    //Re use the visible views
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        EventList listItem = cursor.get(position);
        ImageHelper imageHelper = new ImageHelper();
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ipl);
        Bitmap newIcon = imageHelper.getRoundedCornerBitmap(icon, 200);
        holder.coord.setText(listItem.coord);
        holder.eventName.setText(listItem.eventName);
        holder.location.setText(listItem.location);
        holder.time.setText(listItem.time);
        holder.icon.setImageBitmap(newIcon);
        holder.id = listItem.id;
        holder.day = listItem.day;

        //Checking Bell State Columnview if it is OFF or ON
        if(cursor.getString(YourActivity.COL_EVENTBELL_IMAGEVIEW_STATE).equals("on"))
        {
            holder.bell.setImageResource(R.drawable.bell_on);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.bell.setImageResource(R.drawable.bell_off);
        }

    }
    //Create new views, all to be visible at once
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
    { 
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        EventHolder holder = new EventHolder(view);

        view.setTag(holder);

        return view;
    }
}
```

In your Activity/Fragments you can use the listeners to update the state of the bell, your AlarmClick() will be like this

```
public void alarmClick()
    {
    Cursor cursor = mEventAdapter.getCursor();
    ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();
    String event_bell_state = cursor.getString(YourActivity.COL_EVENT_BELL_IMAGEVIEW_STATE);
    String event_bell_id = cursor.getString(YourActivity.COL_EVENTBELL_ID);

    if(event_bell_state == "on")
    {
        eventValues.put(YourActivity.COL_EVENTBELL_IMAGEVIEW_STATE, "off");
    }
    else
    {
        eventValues.put(YourActivity.COL_EVENTBELL_IMAGEVIEW_STATE, "on");
    }

    String whereClause = YourActivity.COL_EVENTBELL_ID + " = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(event_bell_id)};

    getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().update(EventEntry.CONTENT_URI, eventValues, whereClause, selectionArgs);
    mEventAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(EVENTLIST_LOADER, null, this);
    }
```